# JavaScript variable is not defined at onclick button while calling a function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, onclick

I'm trying to pass a PHP variable into an `onclick()` in a bootstrap button, here's the code, please note that it's in a PHP echo:

```
<button id="reportTopicButt" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="reportTopic('.$topicID.')">
<i class="fa fa-flag"></i></button>
```

**$topicID** is a PHP variable that I get from a query and it's declared inside a PHP function, that's why that code above is an echo statement.

Here's my `reportTopic()` JavaScript function:

```
   function reportTopic(aTopicID) {
        var topicID = aTopicID;

        $.ajax({
            url:"report-topic.php?topicID=" + topicID,  
            type: "GET", 

            success:function(data) {
                var results = data;  
                console.debug(results);

                alert('Thanks for reporting');
        }});
    }
```

The funny thing is that the Chrome console prints the ID I need out, but it gives me the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: CRFYLtWNDD is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick
```

**CRFYLtWNDD** is my **$topicID** PHP variable, so at least I know that the `onclick()` button gets it correctly, but I really can't figure out why it's not defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is because $topicId is rendered as a variable to solve it set it as a string inside your php

```
<button id="reportTopicButt" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="reportTopic(\''.$topicID.'\')">
<i class="fa fa-flag"></i></button>
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you are passing a string to you function you should include it between ' ' if you dont do this javasript thinks you are passing a variable thats why you get the undefined error

Try this

```
onclick="reportTopic(\''.$topicID.'\')">
```